# Way to implement transaction rollback and insert a log in to a table in Snowflake

Tags: sql-server, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have used SQL Server for a long time and switched to Snowflake recently. I need to implement a transaction log as T-SQL in Snowflake so far I have only came across transactions only how can I make a try catch block like below in Snowflake? Without any sps?

Thanks in advance!

```
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        DELETE mytable
    
        INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (5);
        INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ('hello');
 
        COMMIT TRAN -- Transaction Success!
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK TRAN --RollBack in case of Error
 
    INSERT INTO LOGTABLE ("Error",1)

    RAISERROR('error', 1, 1)
END CATCH
```

Comment: I'm afraid you cannot unless you use stored procedure.

Comment: Is there a way to insert a record when a transaction failed?

Comment: Not directly as far as I know, but using a try/catch block in a stored procedure.

Comment: Side point: I'm not entirely convinced this code is correct anyway: Two `INSERT`s could be one statement, and `RAISERROR` should be `THROW:`, and you should also use `SET XACT_ABORT ON;` to prevent hanging transactions

Comment: Hi I have only written a sample query using tsql. just to convey the idea. Sorry if i confuses you.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there is no official support for this in Snowflake yet. But referring to the announcement from Snowflake Summit 2021, it should appear in the public preview this year. Patience, the photo shows a slide from one of the presentations with announcements at Snowflake Summit 2021.

[image]